# Como navegar entre as abas de um painel bootstrap por link href?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Então galera, estou com um problema... eu quero fazer um cadastro e quando eu processar ele em php eu quero que ele retorne em uma determinada aba do painel.. como faço isso?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$('a[href="#home"]').tab('show');
```

**EDIT**

Para usar ao carregar a Página use no evento de `document.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href="#home"]').tab('show');
});
```

**ou** sua abreviação:

```
$(function(){
    $('a[href="#home"]').tab('show');
});
```

Onde `#home` é o `href` da sua tab

Source:

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs)

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $('a[href="#home"]').tab('show');
})
```

```css
.btn{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<button class="btn btn-default">Ir para Tab Home</button>
```

Comment: Como executa a função javascript ao carregar a pagina?

Comment: @LucasFonseca Alterei minha resposta, espero ter Ajudado!